# Hosting apache camel project on Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy, apache-camel

I need help in hosting apache camel project on Tomcat.

I have compiled and run the sample example (camel-example-cxf-proxy) to create proxy in Apache Camel. It is working fine. But here, I have to manually run it when I need proxy. Also, if I need more proxies I will have to do same.

My requirement is that when I start the tomcat, somehow this camel project is hosted and I can use the proxy link. Similarly, when tomcat is down the proxy would be down as well.

Is there any way to deploy this proxy project on tomcat.

Any lead would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So you have found the examples. There you have an [example with CXF ready to be deployed into Tomcat](http://camel.apache.org/cxf-tomcat-example.html).

A preferred way to create Camel web apps that can be deployed in Tomcat is to use the maven archetype.  Run mvn archetype:generate from a terminal and look for: org.apache.camel.archetypes:camel-archetype-web